# Is it possible to define a function for every point in its domain such that every point maps to its family of open balls without the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose I want to define a function $f:X\to \mathcal{F}$ where $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of a family of all open balls for every $x\in X$, more formally <sup>1</sup>:

> $\displaystyle \mathcal{F}:=\{ Z \in \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(X) : (\exists x\in X)(\forall Y\in \mathcal{P}(X)) \left[ Y\in Z \leftrightarrow (\exists \epsilon>0) (Y=B(x,\epsilon)\right] \}$

Now if I can show $(\forall x\in X)(\exists ! Z\in\mathcal{F})(\forall Y\in Z)\left[x\in Y\right]$, can I then use this formula to define $f(x):=Z$ for that unique $Z$ without appealing to the axiom of choice?

---

*Footnote.*

1. Apologies for the readability as I eschewed using the axiom of choice by ensuring that the set formed did not use it. The set $T:=\{\{B(x,\epsilon) : \epsilon>0\}_{x} \in \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(X) : x\in X  \}$ is exactly the set $\mathcal{F}$ above, but I'm not sure if I needed the axiom of choice to form $T$.

Comment: As long as you don't ask that $f$ be injective, sure: just send $x$ to $B(x,17)$ for all $x$. This doesn't require choice at all. It does, however, use the metric structure:  it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is a non-compact topological space $X$ with a base of open sets with compact closures such that there is no function assigning to each point $x\in X$ an open $U\ni x$ with $cl(U)$ compact. (Nothing particularly special is being used about compactness here; the point is that I need to rule out things like "just map $x$ to $X$ itself" - any type of "smallness notion" would do.)

Comment: Suppose I define $f:X\to\mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x):= \{B(x,\epsilon)\in\mathcal{P}(X) : \epsilon >0\}$ (which satisfies $(\forall x\in X)(\exists ! Z\in\mathcal{F})(\forall Y\in Z)\left[x\in Y\right]$ above). I did not a priori stipulate that $f$ be injective but it turns out it is. But is this okay since I did not have to make an arbitrary choice (since for all $x\in X$, $f(x)$ is explicitly given by a formula, namely the set with the property given) so I can rest assured that I did not implicitly invoke $\sf AC$?

Comment: Also with your example of a non-compact topological space, is the reason why you mention this is because in general if I want a function $g:X\to\mathcal{P}$ such that $x\mapsto B(x,r_x)$ for some $r_x>0$ this would require $\sf AC$ (require in the sense so as to guarantee that there is such a function, so just because my space is not compact doesn't necessarily mean I cannot find a choice function without $\sf AC$)?